# Extensions in gnome 3 are not working. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I installed Netspeed and Nightlight slider extensions to my Gnome 3 but these are not working even after I restarted the gnome and then the whole OS. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: gnome now has a built in nightlight feature in Settings -> Devices -> Displays... looking into netspeed now

Comment: how did you install netspeed, can you edit your question with some more info on that

Comment: I clicked on 'Software' and then typed Netspeed in the search bar and installed the extension from there, same with the Nightlight Slider one.

Comment: ok, answer coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 uses Gnome instead of Unity, and you need to install/enable some things differently.

**Nightlight**

Gnome has this feature built in now.

Go to `settings`->`devices`->`display` and turn on "Night Light"

**Netspeed**

This is now a Gnome Extension. It, and many other useful extensions can be installed via apt.

From the command line install extensions and tweak tool:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool
```

You will need to reboot, then run:

```
gnome-tweaks
```

and you can then enable the desired extensions by clicking the extension button on the left of the window.

Comment: Even in 16.04 I was using Gnome 3 as my DE and I also have gnome tweaks already installed but the extensions tab in it didn't have anything in it but I just updated it and the extension tabs now have all my extensions. l turned the required ones ON and the extensions are working now. Thanks!

Comment: you bet. please accept answer and upvote :) thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote. I don't have enough 'reputation' to do so.